# Зачем нужно двойное отрицание?

Tags: c++

Я всегда не понимал, зачем пишут код с двойным отрицанием, например вот кусок:

```
#define MI_UNLIKELY(arg) __builtin_expect(!!(arg), 0)
```

Зачем тут нужно двойное отрицание?
Если для того, чтобы проверить, что значение приводится к bool, то в чём смысл, если в противном случае ошибки всё равно не избежать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это модная альтернатива `bool(arg)`. Ее чаще можно увидеть в старом C, где нет типа `bool` (`_Bool`).

По сути она делает что-то типа `arg == 0 ? 0 : 1`.

Comment: ее часто можно увидеть у javascript, где с типизацией не заладилось с самого начала:)

Comment: А почему я не могу написать тот же код без `!!`?

Comment: @AntonMitrochin Тогда `MI_UNLIKELY(42)` станет возвращать `42` вместо `1`. Насколько это плохо - сложно сказать. Мне принудительный каст в bool кажется хорошей вещью.

Comment: приведение к `bool` ничего не даёт для `if`. Больше пользы будет, если работать, например с битовыми масками. `!!arg` == `(arg?1:0)`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, в случае `if` компилятор удалит код приведения к `bool`. А если нет разницы, зачем менять код?

Comment: Ещё в vc++ есть [предупреждение C4800](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4800?view=msvc-170), которое можно получить при (не)явном преобразовании в `bool` ([enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/206564)). Иногда для борьбы с этим предупреждением используют двойное отрицание или какой-нибудь иной трюк  вместо явного приведения типа. Хотя, конечно, использование `__builtin_expect` слегка намекает, что у ТС проблем с данным предупреждением нет.